# Translated version of a convex set is convex

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be a convex set in a vector space $V$. Let $w$ be an arbitrary element of $V$. Let $w+S$ be the set of all elements $w+v$ where $v\in S$. Show that $w+S$ is convex.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ Let $v_1,v_2 \in S$, $w+v_1, w+v_2 \in w+S$, and $0 \leq t \leq 1$.
$$(1-t) (w+v_1) + t(w+v_2) = w -wt + (1-t)v_1 + wt + tv_2 = w + (1-t)v_1 + tv_2$$

Since $S$ is convex we have $(1-t)v_1 + tv_2 \in S$, so $w+(1-t)v_1 + tv_2 \in w+S$. $\quad \rm{QED}$

Does this constitute a proof? Can anyone criticize this?

Comment: No criticism equals no problem

Comment: Your proof is correct..

Comment: Thanks @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг